# Как сохранить AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Есть класс, отнаследованный от `AsyncTask`, который скачивает большие данные с сервера. Во время скачивания показывается progress dialog. 
Когда пользователь нажимает клавишу "Home" - активность, к которой привязан класс, уничтожается, а скачивание продолжается. Как при создании активности подцепить эту асинхронную задачу и заново показать диалог? Пробовал через `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` сохранять объект `AsyncTask`, но в Android 4.0 этот метод уже не вызывается системой.

Answer (score 2):

может вам сделать этот класс с единственным экземпляром? что бы каждый раз когда вы его вызываете вы будете обрашатся на один и тот же экземпляр класса

```
public class Noviy extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private static Noviy instance;

    private Noviy() {}

    public synchronized static Noviy getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new Noviy();
        }
        return instance;
    }

}
```

и использовать

```
Noviy noviy = Noviy.getInstance();
noviy.execute("");
```

Answer (score 0):

Разберись с этим [уроком](http://startandroid.ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/154-urok-91-asynctask-povorot-ekrana.html) - должно помочь решить твою проблему

Comment: Я же пишу, что `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance` почему-то не вызывается системой.

Comment: android:configChanges - такое в манифесте есть?

Comment: Нет, не использую.

Comment: но стоит android:screenOrientation="landscape", так приложение работает только в этом режиме.

Comment: убери с манифеста и поставь в онКриейт - this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

Comment: При повороте экрана все работает:
onSaveInstanceState()
onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()
onDestroy()
при Home key 
onSaveInstanceState()
onDestroy()

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо сохранять в `onSaveInstanceState()` и восстанавливать в `onCreate()`

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            // восстанавливаем тут, активити пересоздалось
        } else {
            // активити запустилось первый раз
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Выполняйте загрузку больших файлов не в `AsyncTask`, а в `Service`. Таким образом, если Ваша `Activity` будет убита - `Service` продолжит работу и докачает файл.

Прогресс при этом можно отображать как в виде оповещения Android, так и передавать в `Activity` через `ResultReceiver` или `BroadcastReceiver`.

Также почитайте про [BoundService](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/components/bound-services.html).